# Crystal Reports - Sum shared variables, save copy of sum to global variable, reset sum to 0 on group change

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that contains a subreport. I have no problem bringing in the shared variables from the subreport. I also have no problem summarizing the shared variables and resetting them to 0 on a change of group.

The problem I am having is, before I reset the sum to 0, I must save a copy of the current group's sum total onto a global variable to be accessed in the following group footer.

I need the sum total from Group Footer 5 to perform calculations with it in Group Footer 4.

I then need the calculation from (Group Footer 5 - Group Footer 4) saved onto another global variable so I can then use it to perform calculations in Group Footer 3.. and so on and so forth.

**EDIT**

This is a short example of what I am trying to accomplish.

Group Footer 5:

```
// Initialize (maybe in separate formula?)
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar G5total;

G5total := {@MySharedSum};

// Separate reset formula for MySharedSum
{@MySharedSum} := 0;
```

Group Footer 4:

```
// Initialize (maybe in separate formula?)
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar G4total;
Global NumberVar G4calc;

G4total := {@MySharedSum};
G4calc := (G5total - G4total)
// maybe I have to declare G5total as [Global NumberVar G5total;] ?

// Separate reset formula for MySharedSum
{@MySharedSum} := 0;
```

Group Footer 3:

```
// Initialize (maybe in separate formula?)
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar G3total;
Global NumberVar G3calc;

G3total := {@MySharedSum};
G3calc := (G4calc - G3total)
// maybe I have to declare G4calc as [Global NumberVar G4calc;] ?

// Separate reset formula for MySharedSum
{@MySharedSum} := 0;
```

I apologize for not being thorough- hopefully that helps explain a bit more what I am trying to do :)

Any ideas? Am I asking Crystal to do too much?

Assistance, criticism, etc is more than welcomed.

This report is so close to being finished! ..

Thank you SO,

gtm

Comment: Welcome to SO!  A picture (or two) is worth a thousand words in this case.  Also, editing your question to include related code will convey what you have tried and help people to better help you.

Comment: Updated code example. Thank you for the nice reply! I will be more thorough.

Comment: your approach seems to be fine... what issue you are facing? what is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It must be an issue with the placement of my reset formula and the formulas to assign the global variables then. If my approach seems to be ok, it must be my error somewhere. Thanks again Siva